# Overriding Ctrl+H in vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'm sorry, for some reason I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to map my backspace button to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in my vimrc file. I've looked a lot online, and haven't found anything that seems to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your terminal type, and set your `$TERM` to correct value.  It's not a good idea to use map in vim to work around this issue.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look of these two pages: http://www.helpdesk.umd.edu/topics/applications/terminal/tera_term/1105/ and http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
:imap ^H <Left><Del>
```

So does:

```
:imap ^H <BS>
```

Comment: Neither of those have worked for me. I'm running Ubuntu 64 bit. Any idea why that wouldn't work?

Comment: What mode are you trying to use the mapping in? insert mode?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried every combination of ^h, <C-h> <BS>, and <Left><Del>. I'm putting them in my .vimrc file, no luck.

Comment: If you are putting them in your `.vimrc` don't include the `:` at the front.  But you still didn't answer my question, are you trying to use the key binding in insert mode? normal mode? visual mode?

Comment: Insert mode, I think. (Whatever the mode is after you hit "a" to edit)

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange.  Try typing `:verbose imap ^H` while in `vim` and let me know what it says.

Comment: `i  ^H            <BS>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
Press ENTER or type command to continue`